# Universally Accessible Variable?

Tags: c#

I want to increase "BrainsEaten" each time any instance of Zombie executes EatBrains.
How can I make this happen?

```
namespace ZombieLand
{
    public int BrainsEaten; // <- This is syntactically incorrect, but illustrates what I want

    public class Zombie
    {
        public void EatBrains()
        {
            BrainsEaten++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to create methods for when the zombie eats other body parts.

Comment: @Adam Maybe the body part could be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're describing is called a *global variable*, and they don't exist in C#.

What you can create, though, is a static variable (or, more appropriately, a static property) on a class. Static members are not tied to a specific instance of a class but to a class itself, allowing you to access them without requiring an instance to work with.

For example:

```
namespace Zomebieland
{
    public class Zombie
    {
        public static int BrainsEaten {get; private set;}

        public void EatBrains()
        {
            BrainsEaten++;
        }
    }
}
```

This did two things: it moved the declaration of `BrainsEaten` inside the `Zombie` class and made it `static`. Additionally, I turned it into a property with a public `get` and a private `set`, so the `Zombie` class can assign (or, in this case, increment) the value, but code outside of the `Zombie` class can only read the value.

Comment: Will using static classes show signs of inefficiency if 12m brains are eaten?

Comment: @Soo: Just the opposite actually... If you omit the static keyword, then every Zombie instance has an int as part of its memory. Then you have 12m brain counts, which on top of being unsynchronized is a huge waste of memory. Think of a static variable (not a static class incidentally) as a variable that is global and shared, but only within the class. Believe it or not, that really is good enough in pretty much all applications.

Comment: @Soo: The value class won't behave any differently, regardless of how many times you increment it.

Comment: My code is getting an OutOfMemoryException.  Could this static element be why?

Answer (score 0):

Use a static member variable INSIDE your class:

```
public static int BrainsEaten;
```

This becomes a global variable common to all objects of the class.
You cannot declare it outside as part of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable BrainsEaten static like this:

```
public static int BrainsEaten;
```

And of course you need to define the variable inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a static variable.

```
public static int BrainsEaten;
```